# Trying to access element with custom attribute

Tags: jquery, html

The below image shows a div, and I am trying to access another element inside this.

[image: div image]

> hype_scene_index=1

The above is the div which I need to look in.

```
var home = $('.home_' + element.innerHTML).find('div[hype_scene_index=1]');
```

So I am looking for a div with a class named `home_O`.  There are more than one scene index, and their might be more than one instance of `home_O`, so I am looking for the closest one that matches an element. The element is a class named: letter, and it's `innerHTML` might be 'O'.

Ideal outcome is that the element within the parent is searched, and found so I can get the element ID, as its auto generated.

But my code keeps giving me null, so I assume its not finding the parent?

```
<body>
<!-- copy these lines to your document: -->
<div id="index_hype_container" style="margin: auto; position: relative; width: 750px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform-style: flat;" aria-live="polite" hyp_dn="index" aria-hidden="false">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="index.hyperesources/index_hype_generated_script.js?62731"></script>
    <div id="HYPE_persistent_symbols" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="HYPE_scene" id="hype-scene-OjWA3NVziFMIKuSh" hype_scene_index="0" aria-hidden="true" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: none; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 750px; height: 400px;">
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element home_O" id="hype-obj-wesKKEBfzoAtPRxZ" style="pointer-events: auto;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element letter" id="letter_U" style="pointer-events: auto;">U</div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="hype-obj-waKDfvZQplJiCqeO" style="pointer-events: auto;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="letter_L" style="pointer-events: auto;">L</div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element letter" id="hype-obj-7ollG3cYWGzedsFl" style="pointer-events: auto;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element letter" id="hype-obj-CscCOdYjMl41hKGi" style="pointer-events: auto;">W</div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="hype-obj-3tEr1wAfKsMqpvu2" style="pointer-events: auto;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="letter_D" style="pointer-events: auto;">D</div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element letter" id="hype-obj-QhJNaIx9jqpTUf5q" style="pointer-events: auto;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element letter" id="hype-obj-I80tbqlCSZETYuEZ" style="pointer-events: auto;">O</div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="hype-obj-Iusjm7VpM40usoo0" style="pointer-events: auto;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element home_W" id="hype-obj-nNtpj04d3AH9T6wf" style="pointer-events: auto;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="hype-obj-5YaBwame06tuiSj4" style="pointer-events: auto;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element home_U" id="hype-obj-rFxSKEz5Eukvr4ZJ" style="pointer-events: auto;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="hype-obj-EuujdQE5TaxENR9k" style="pointer-events: auto;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element home_L" id="hype-obj-10ZyCk0M63Fw2slH" style="pointer-events: auto;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="hype-obj-6tUMHuYLAOzlSyxl" style="pointer-events: auto;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element home_D" id="hype-obj-hXSdkjrNFocxYwmB" style="pointer-events: auto;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="hype-obj-2xBwMAvPrZl3dOLx" style="pointer-events: auto;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="hype-obj-eRFLNRAxqYwORHwR" style="pointer-events: auto;">NEXT</div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="hype-obj-nFfnSL7IdjX0axbL" style="pointer-events: auto;">Play Word</div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="hype-obj-HnHXxR6ibWzr00Gt" style="pointer-events: auto;">Attempts</div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="attWould" style="pointer-events: auto;">0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="HYPE_scene" id="hype-scene-o2BqYOPBF2QH1PUw" hype_scene_index="1" aria-hidden="false" aria-flowto="hype-obj-UaS00dz2vE3iBhqe" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: block; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 750px; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 400px; -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) rotateY(0deg); z-index: 1; opacity: 1;">
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none; z-index: 16;">
            <div class="HYPE_element home_O" id="hype-obj-UaS00dz2vE3iBhqe" aria-flowto="hype-obj-qPeLTvGhcjw2VjHy" style="pointer-events: auto; position: absolute; border: 1px solid rgb(216, 221, 228); background-color: rgb(232, 235, 237); overflow: visible; z-index: 16; width: 100px; height: 100px; top: 133px; left: 18px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none; z-index: 15;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="hype-obj-2QwLlYCvjNdrWcn8" aria-flowto="hype-obj-SQrNXiMZLdjtTO2x" style="pointer-events: auto; position: absolute; overflow: visible; z-index: 15; width: 90px; height: 93px; top: 249px; left: 24px;">
                <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none; z-index: 23;">
                    <div class="HYPE_element letter" id="hype-obj-qPeLTvGhcjw2VjHy" aria-flowto="hype-obj-2QwLlYCvjNdrWcn8" style="pointer-events: auto; position: absolute; z-index: 23; border: 1px solid rgb(216, 221, 228); -webkit-user-select: none; background-color: rgb(232, 235, 237); -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%; -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); line-height: 95px; font-size: 96px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; cursor: move; overflow: visible; width: 88px; height: 91px; top: -11px; left: 0px;">O</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none; z-index: 13;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="hype-obj-SQrNXiMZLdjtTO2x" role="button" aria-flowto="hype-obj-P4Ab8SRhfBmvdNZl" style="pointer-events: auto; position: absolute; z-index: 13; border: 1px solid rgb(160, 160, 160); padding: 6px; opacity: 0; -webkit-user-select: none; background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240); word-wrap: break-word; display: inline; font-size: 13px; text-align: center; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; overflow: visible; width: 55px; height: 15px; top: 220px; left: 665px;">NEXT</div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none; z-index: 12;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="hype-obj-P4Ab8SRhfBmvdNZl" role="button" aria-flowto="hype-obj-Fx4hwSdz6cqIV42C" style="pointer-events: auto; position: absolute; z-index: 12; border: 1px solid rgb(160, 160, 160); padding: 6px; -webkit-user-select: none; background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240); word-wrap: break-word; display: inline; font-size: 13px; text-align: center; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; overflow: visible; width: 90px; height: 15px; top: 16px; left: 262px;">Play Word</div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none; z-index: 10;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="hype-obj-Fx4hwSdz6cqIV42C" aria-flowto="attOr" style="pointer-events: auto; position: absolute; padding: 8px; overflow: visible; word-wrap: break-word; z-index: 10; white-space: nowrap; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; display: inline; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-weight: bold; top: 0px; left: 0px;">Attempts</div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none; z-index: 9;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="attOr" style="pointer-events: auto; position: absolute; border: 1px solid rgb(216, 221, 228); line-height: 28px; background-color: rgb(232, 235, 237); overflow: visible; z-index: 9; text-align: center; width: 34px; height: 28px; top: 23px; left: 14px;">0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="HYPE_scene" id="hype-scene-2YkRRXgevxQb8pAU" hype_scene_index="2" aria-hidden="true" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: none; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 750px; height: 400px;">
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="hype-obj-te69tWEj33olYKwS" style="pointer-events: auto;">Math is awesome and everyone should know it!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="HYPE_element_container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
            <div class="HYPE_element" id="hype-obj-sYebDLAnAIGcH1H7" style="pointer-events: auto;">This is a story about Math!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end copy -->
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you were to post the actual HTML.  We can all guess, but it sounds like this would be a simple problem to solve for you if we had enough information.

Comment: @BenjaminRay Code Added :)

Comment: Clarify for me please which element you have, which one you want, and what information you have about the one you want.  I'm not sure if you're trying to end up with home_0, or you are starting with home_0 and want to end up with letter_0, or HYPE_scene, etc.

Comment: @BenjaminRay I have also tried this: `var home = $(this).find('.home_' + element.innerHTML + ':first');'  So it looks at the element, and finds the closest div with a class named = 'home_O'  The $(this) is draggable, and I need it to find the closest div to it.  There are more than one.

Answer (score 1):

find() searches down the DOM tree (children), and closest() searches the next matching parent up the DOM tree.

Here are some examples of how you can move between your elements, assuming you have the element from which you are getting the letter (e.g. element.innerHTML):

JavaScript:

```
// Not sure how you get element in the first place, but I trust this gives you the letter (e.g. 'O')
var letter = element.innerHTML;

// To get the parent HYPE_scene from home_O:
var parent = $('.home_' + letter).closest('.HYPE_scene');

// To get the child with the ID letter_O:
var child = parent.find('#letter_' + letter);

// Modified version of the JS you originally posted:
var home = $('.home_' + letter).closest('div[hype_scene_index=1]');
```

Comment: Not sure why, each of those gives me null :(  The bottom one, should work without any issue.  The second one down should also work, but it doesn't and gives me null.  No error, just null, as if it could not find a div that matches

Comment: The element, btw, is the draggable letter.  Its for spelling words :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.find()` to try to find a parent, when `.find()` is only useful for finding children. Instead, use `.closest()`:

```
var $home = $('.home_O').closest('div[hype_scene_index=1]');
```

Comment: I did try closest, but it did not work. Still gives me null ?

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/bpuaLx3k/  I updated my answer because I was using "home_0" instead of "home_O". If your code is not working using `$('.home_' + element.innerHTML)`, then you need to consider the value of `element.innerHTML`.

Comment: If it's an individual element it works fine, but when there is more than one, I cannot find the closest to the element.  Strange it works in the fiddle, but not in on the page.  Ill have a look at the element.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Benjamin Ray, I have managed to fix this deep find issue with the following code:

```
var home = $(element).closest($('.HYPE_scene')).find($('.home_' + element.innerHTML));
```

NOTE: $(element) is the draggable div, looking for its closest corresponding home.